# htaccess: entity tags not applying to ico files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've been using the following code for some time to apply far future expiration dates to static files and enable gzip compression, however I've recently noticed that it does not seem to work well with .ico files. Much research has not yielded an answer - any help/thoughts/clues appreciated.

```
#####################################################
# CONFIGURE media caching
#
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2020 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|php|html)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
#
#####################################################
```

Comment: Include request and response headers?  Tough to understand what doesn't "work well".

Comment: It literally doesn't set the expiration dates for .ico files

Comment: Still no headers in the question?

Comment: Make sure your .ico files permission set to something that server can modify !

Comment: This code is actually working fine for me on my copy of apache. It would be very helpful to see the headers being returned for requests.

Comment: Have you got mod_expires installed? May be a conflict between two methods of setting an expiry header.

Comment: Just tried this, and it worked fine. I even diffed the response headers to be sure, and the Etag removal and Expires addition were perfect. Since this is a server config issue, maybe provide some more details (Apache version and config dump ... minimally any other .htaccess rules in the tree). It's possible something in the main Apache config like AllowOverride is restricting you (although that works on a <Directory> context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess at a conflict between mod_expires and explicit setting of the header, as these give two different ways to set an expiry header.

Unfortunately without seeing some examples of actual headers in the question (or more of the configuration) there aren't really enough clues.  Are expiry headers being sent with the wrong date, or not being sent at all? If the date is "wrong", the expiry header could be getting replaced by mod_expiry

Note that [RFC2616 Section 14.21](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) states that an expiry date should not be more than one year in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe .ICO files size is so little, that sending back a 304 would not bring any benefits in terms of server load.

Comment: there is no limit u can set for even 0 byte files then gzip it the only limitation to small files is [rule of thumb and small files with hadoop](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/)